# Angular2 - HTML form on submit downloads pdf

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am very new to angular2. I need to have multiple input fields that a user would fill in , and upon submit, a PDF containing the fields they input would be downloaded. I'm trying to use jspdf but I am unsure if i'm using it correct. In this case, if the user inputs a `name` and selects a `power`, I want to download a document that contains both the name and power they selected. I don't think I'm calling those elements right though because I'm using `{{model.name}}` and `{{model.power}}`, and this is where my errors come in. Thanks.

documentation.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, } from '@angular/core';
import {Documentation} from "./documentation";
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-documentation',
  templateUrl: './documentation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./documentation.component.css'],
  providers: [
    { provide: 'Window',  useValue: window }
  ]
})
export class DocumentationComponent  {

  powers = ['Really Smart', 'Super Flexible',
  'Super Hot', 'Weather Changer'];

model = new Documentation(18, 'Dr IQ', this.powers[0], 'Chuck Overstreet');

submitted = false;

onSubmit() {  
   var doc = new jsPDF();
   doc.text(20, 20, {{model.name}});
   doc.text(20, 30, {{model.power}});
   doc.addPage();
   doc.text(20, 20, 'success!');

   // Save the PDF
   doc.save('Test.pdf');
 }
}
```

documentation.ts

```
export class Documentation {

    constructor(
      public id: number,
      public name: string,
      public power: string,
      public alterEgo?: string
    ) {  }

  }
```

documentation.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hero Form</h1>
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #documentationForm="ngForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label class = "name" for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
                           required
                           [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name"
                           #name="ngModel">
                    <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
                         class="alert alert-danger">
                      Name is required
                    </div>
              </div>


          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="alterEgo">Alter Ego</label>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="alterEgo"
                   [(ngModel)]="model.alterEgo" name="alterEgo">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="power">Hero Power</label>
            <select class="form-control"  id="power"
                    required
                    [(ngModel)]="model.power" name="power">
              <option *ngFor="let pow of powers" [value]="pow">{{pow}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!documentationForm.form.valid">Download</button>

        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (19:38)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     DocumentationComponent.prototype.onSubmit = function () {
|         var doc = new jsPDF();
|         doc.text(20, 20, {}, { model: .name });
|     };
|     ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually we get instance in constructor, and use this.model not {{model}}.

```
class ... {
    model = null;
    constructor() {
        this.model = new Documentation(18, 'Dr IQ', this.powers[0], 'Chuck Overstreet');
    }
onSubmit() {  
   var doc = new jsPDF();
   doc.text(20, 20, this.model.name);
   doc.text(20, 30, this.model.power);
   doc.addPage();
   doc.text(20, 20, 'success!');

   // Save the PDF
   doc.save('Test.pdf');
 }
}
```